# Admob Ad only shows after resuming game

Tags: android, admob, surfaceview, ads

I have a game where I'm using a surfaceView and no XML layout.

The code in my main activity:

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    // test ad ID
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"); //test ad ID anyone can use
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(
            "xxxxxx").build();
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    adView.setLayoutParams(lp);
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    layout.addView(renderView);
    layout.addView(adView);
    setContentView(layout);
```

What happens when I run the game is, I enter the main menu screen and there is no ad on display. However, if I press the android button to leave the app but then return to it, the ad appears and shows at the bottom of the main menu screen.

Any ideas what's going on? Been working on this for some hours no but to no avail, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `adView.loadAd(adRequest);` until after `setContentView(layout);`

Comment: I did that, but the problem persisted. Funnily enough though what did fix it was simply adding this line before adding it to the layout: adView.setBackgroundColor(0); This however seems like a hackish solution I'm not incredibly comfortable with, but so far it's my best bet :(